# AWS Command Line questions

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, command-line

I am new in AWS. I have few questions about command line.

```
1. `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf`
```

This command is for make file system. What does -t means?

```
2. `umount -d /dev/xvdf`
```

This command is for umount file system. What does -d means?

Is there any source I can learn abut these commands like -t, -s, -d ....

Comment: Google is your best friend. `mkfs -t` - here -t denotes file type, `umount -d` - here -d means if  unmounted device was a loop device, also free this loop device. some links - https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs

Comment: Try the 'man' command to read the manual page for a giveb command, i.e., 'man mkfs'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When using the mkfs wrapper, include the -t fstype option to specify the type of file system to be built. If not specified, the default file system type, ext2, is created.
   (https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs)
2. -d is used in case the unmounted device was a loop device, also free this loop device.
   (https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount)

Answer (score 0):

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf
```

Here -t denotes "File System".

and:

```
umount -d /dev/xvdf
```

Here "umount" use to unmounted and -d denotes the unmounted device was a loop device, also free this loop device.